# Displaying products from static block in phtml file

Tags: category, products

I've got a static block in which I'm getting the products from a specific category so like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="429" column_count="4"  mode="grid" limit="50"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Now I'm trying to call this static block in my phtml file like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products')->toHtml();
    ?>
```

But it doesn't show the products on the page.
I've tried adding the code of the static block to a cms page and then the products are showing, just not for the page with the phtml file.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your requirement you need to add block permission.

> Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks

Add following code in block permission.

```
catalog/product_list
```

Thanks,

Comment: It's set in the permissons already so that shouldn't be the issue